# Transforming odom to base-link and then to map

Tags: navigation, odometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a robotic application, I get odometry on /odom. However, I don't have a robot state publisher, so I'm publishing my own transforms. I want to know whether they are right:

1. odom->base_link: identity transform
2. map->base_link: When tf starts, I note the pose given by odometry. Then as the robot moves to a new position, I take the new odometry readings and compute the new pose. The values in new_pose-old_pose are broadcast.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10673/transforming-odom-to-base-link-and-then-to-map/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://answers.ros.org/question/1621/transform-base_link-to-base_lasermapodom) answer might be helpful

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1